Does randomness help depth?
Suppose we have a $RNC^i$ or $BPNC^i$ algorithm for a problem, is it suspected that the problem has an $NC^i$ algorithm or just an $NC^j$ algorithm for some $j\geq i$?
Is there any evidence for whether randomness helps or not helps depth akin to evidence for $P=BPP$?
